# Editing textfield after "endEdit" with ShouldChangeCharactersInRange implemented

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I have the following code implemented to restrict my user to enter in more than 2 decimal points and places after they have entered the first one. Users can still edit the textfield as long as they don't "leave" or "endEdit" the textfield. However, once they leave the textfield and go back, the textfield is not editable. How can I solve this problem?

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
if (textField == self.SalesAmounttext)
{
    NSString *newString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];

    NSString *expression = @"^([0-9]+)?(\\.([0-9]{1,2})?)?$";

    NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:expression
                                                                           options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                                                             error:nil];
    NSUInteger numberOfMatches = [regex numberOfMatchesInString:newString
                                                        options:0
                                                          range:NSMakeRange(0, [newString length])];
    if (numberOfMatches == 0)
        return NO;
}

return YES;
}
```

Comment: Not editable at all? Not even deletion? What about `clearsOnInsertion`?

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do was add in the clearsOnInsertion code and everything works! Thanks to @Wain

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
if (textField == self.SalesAmounttext)
{

textField.clearsOnInsertion=YES ; // HERE

NSString *newString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];

NSString *expression = @"^([0-9]+)?(\\.([0-9]{1,2})?)?$";

NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:expression
                                                                       options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                                                         error:nil];
NSUInteger numberOfMatches = [regex numberOfMatchesInString:newString
                                                    options:0
                                                      range:NSMakeRange(0, [newString length])];
if (numberOfMatches == 0)
    return NO;
}

return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logic places very tight restrictions on the user so any arbitrary edit will not be permitted. From a user standpoint that will probably be quite confusing so good options would be:

1. Set `clearsOnInsertion` when the text field is created so that each edit is a fresh start
2. Alert the user about invalid edits
3. Allow each edit and then format at the end of editing and alert the user to any issue then